# RO Chat Message Delete Option

Tags: script, chat, room-owners

### Description:

Gives room owners the ability to delete other users' chat messages from the message popup menu:

[image]

On confirmation, [the message will be deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZNJg.png). The ability is available for up to 2 minutes after a message is posted.

### Download:

- [Github](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/blob/master/RODeleteMessages.user.js)
- [Github raw](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/raw/master/RODeleteMessages.user.js)

### Features:

- Verified to work on both Chrome and Firefox.
- Asks for confirmation before deleting.

### Issues:

- This will only work for messages that have been added since you joined the room. If this is an issue it's rather trivial to fix at the expense of potentially leaving the "delete" action in the pop-up for longer than the 2 minute time limit. Let me know.
- Given that this isn't publicly exposed, I almost get the feeling that the ability is a bug. I wouldn't be surprised if it were removed some day.
- Report bugs or other issues in comments here.

---

[Check out my other scripts.](https://stackapps.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a25350%20is%3aq%20%5bscript%5d%20)

Comment: Does this work on feed messages?

Comment: @GrahamChiu Yes. Feed item messages can be deleted, although the status messages (e.g. "Jason C has made a change to the feeds posted in this room") can not.

Comment: Looks like they SE finally removed this. :(

Comment: Yep. The response to the POST is "You can only delete your own messages", but the request is considered a "success".